# What is the next shape in this sequence?

Tags: pattern, visual

Which is the next shape in this sequence? Pick from the bottom of line:

[image]

Comment: Does the sequence continue on the second line or do we get to pick one from the bottom line?

Comment: @rhsquared one must pick one of the bottom line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's

> the first one. start with the empty picture, a step is to rotate n clockwise and then add a dot at the top.

Comment: literally was just about to click post answer

Comment: Right, however, I can't get the relation between the first and second shapes. It's not about placing a dot or rotating (At least at the same time)... however that is true for the rest of shapes.

Comment: start with the empty picture, a step is to rotate n clockwise and then add a dot at the top

Comment: The description in your answer is reversed from what you say in the comment; the comment is correct.

Comment: @GendoIkari; i just missed the 'rotate 0' first step - which isn't difficult :)